# Gradle copy from each folder directory in an array

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a list of folder directories in an array saved as a variable called 'folders' in my build.gradle file.

I want to copy from each of these folders into a single directory.

I'm trying the following:

```
task copy(type: Copy) {
    folders.each {
        from it
    }
    into ('build/tmp/asciiDoc')
    include('*.adoc')
}
```

When I run this I get an error telling me 'NO-SOURCE'. I'm not clear what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please give an example one of the folders and also the path of one of the *.adoc files within the folder